# Why was Bistan at the Council meeting?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, the-rebel-alliance

In *Rogue One: A Star Wars Story*, it is established that the Rebel Alliance has a sort of high council made up of senators, squadron leaders, and the like, which made the Alliance's big decisions. If that is true, then why is the space monkey himself, Bistan, there? He is a mere gunner for a u-wing. Why would he be part of a high council to make important decisions?

Comment: I don't recall seeing him there - can you include a screen capture? Also - are you certain it is indeed Bistan, and not another of the same species?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Various non-council members were present at the meeting. Bistan was one of these observers.

It should be noted that he did not participate in the discussion beyond cheering for Jyn at one point.

Comment: agree - it pretty much seems like any rebel on site is in the room